# laravel, ошибка при запуске миграция

Tags: laravel, composer, install, artisan, migrate

Сделал clone laravel проекта, потом сделал composer install. Делаю команду php artisan migrate, и вылетает ошибка:

```
In Connection.php line 647:                                                                                                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.configs' doesn't exist (SQL: select `value` from `configs` where `key` = logo_alt   
  limit 1)
```

Тоже самое если выполнить php artisan, php artisan --version, php artisan serve и т.д.(любую команду с artisan). Кто-нибудь знает что это может быть? 
То же самое при composer install:

```
In Connection.php line 647:
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.config  
  s' doesn't exist (SQL: select `value` from `configs` where `key` = logo_alt  
   limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но похоже ваш проект использует homestead. Почитайте здесь. Для своей версии ларавеля, конечно. Возможно поможет.
https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/homestead
P.S. но это не точно))